# Are following statements undefined or false?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

Consider following cases:

- **example #1**

$$\forall x,y\in\mathbb R\left(\neg\left(\frac{1}{x}\ge y\right)\rightarrow\frac{1}{x}\lt y\right)$$

- **example #2**
  (assuming universe of discourse is all square matrices elements of which are real numbers)
  $$\forall A,B\left(B=B (A A^{-1})\right)$$
  As for example 1 if x is zero then what does the statement evaluate to and as for example 2 what if A and B are not conformable for multiplication or A does not have an inverse? Are these considered undefined or false?

Comment: To evaluate definiteness of statement without providing the language is indecent and it makes this an ill-posed problem. I, for instance, have never seen a language which includes $x^{-1}, y^{-1}, \ldots$, nor $\frac 1 x$, etc. I'd say they are both undefined. **Edit:** Since the universe is that of square matrices, the product always makes sense.

Comment: @GitGud Well it says all square matrices not square matrices of a specific size so we encounter multiplication of a 5*5 matrix by a 8*8 matrix as an example which is undefined

Comment: Of course, you're right. Missed that.

Comment: Even if we limit universe of discourse to a set of square matrices of a specific size the issue of A not having inverse still persists

Comment: For the first case, what with $x=0$?